# Which answer to pick if multiples are correct?

Tags: discussion, answers

If there are multiple answers on your desired question and more than one of them are correct/the same. Which answer should I marked correct?

I have my question - [Java - Serialization - NotSerializableException Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824161/java-serialization-notserializableexception-issue/24824281#24824281) - which has been answered all in about the same time. Just want to make sure I mark the right one

Comment: I would pick the one with the wording you like best to accept, and give the other answers an upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accepting an answer or not is always up to the asker of the question.

I often use the following criteria:

- If the answers are different, I accept the answer that I ended up using to solve my problem.
- If the answers are the same, I accept the one that was posted first.

Don't forget that you can also upvote all the answers that were correct/helpful.

Comment: When they are the same, the time when the first of them had all the information might be different though they were posted at the same time... There's a link to the edit history below posts which were edited (by anyone but the OP, or after the 5 minute grace-period).